# referring to Eqn. 1a) and 1b) in a sentence as eqn. (1)

Tags: labels, subequations

I have two equations. [1a) and 1b)] 
And I want to refer these equations in a sentence as Eqn. (1).
How can I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: are you using `amsmath`?  if so, see p.10, section 3.11.3 of the user's guide (`texdoc amsmath).  it tells how to give a reference to the "parent" number of subequations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a label to the same line as `\begin{subequations}` you can reference that lable.

Comment: A slight nuance: the parent "label" doesn't have to be on the same line with `\begin{subequations}`. What's required is that the parent's `\label` be provided *before* some other counter (likely the `equation` counter) is incremented within the `subequations` environment.